# Pq isso não funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu sou novo mexendo com JS e parece um erro bobo, mas eu travei nele...

Quando eu tento usar o código da seguinte forma, não funciona...

> Assim não funciona

```
<div id="intfloat" onclick="Showmenu()" class="intfloat">
<div id="intfloatM" class="intfloatM"></div>
<div id="intfloatN" class="intfloatN"></div>
<img class="ifimg" src="static/img/others/intfloat.png"/>
</div>
<script>

    function Showmenu() {
        var display = document.getElementById('intfloatM').style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById('intfloatN').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('intfloatM').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('intfloatM').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('intfloatN').style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
```

Mas se eu pegar só uma DIV funciona

> assim funciona

```
function Showmenu() {
        var display = document.getElementById('intfloatM').style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById('intfloatM').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('intfloatM').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Existe alguma restrição ? Ou algo está errado ? ;-;

Comment: cara, não sei exatamente o motivo de fazer desta forma, mas, você não gostaria de tentar o toggleClass? criar uma classe hidden e uma show e então mudar a class com o .toggleClass()?

Comment: Faltam as chaves nos seu if/else, por isso só a primeira linha de cada bloco é realmente condicional, as segundas linhas sempre executam. E verificar se `style.display == 'none'` vai dar problema na primeira vez, porque o valor nesse caso vai ser `''`. Sugiro tentar a sugestão do @flourigh.

Comment: Eu entendi, era um erro bobo a falta das chaves "{}", com elas funcionou normalmente, obg pessoal